# Unable to initialize the database for PostgreSQL-9.6

Tags: postgresql, initialization, centos7, postgresql-9.6

I am setting up a new virtual server to run Netbox, an IP address Management server. I am installing all dependencies and am having trouble with PostgreSQL server database initialization.

I have PostgreSQL 9.6 on CentOS 7, (also tried PostgreSQL 9.5 on CentOS 7, but get same issue).

I have been unable to initialize the database.

The install guides I have found online all say the same thing:

initialize the database as follows:

```
# /usr/pgsql-9.6/bin/postgresql96-setup initdb
```

This results in the following output:

```
-bash: /usr/pgsql-9.6/bin/postgresql96-setup: No such file or directory
```

So it appears that the file "postgresql96-setup" does not exist anywhere on the file system.

I have used the find command to try and locate the file as follows:

```
find / -name "postgresql96-setup"
```

The find command finds nothing.

Below are the contents of folder /usr/pgsql-9.6/bin/

```
[root@prdsw1mgtapp39 bin]# ls -lh
total 9.6M
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  52K May  8 10:08 clusterdb
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  52K May  8 10:08 createdb
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  85K May  8 10:08 createlang
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  57K May  8 10:08 createuser
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  48K May  8 10:08 dropdb
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  85K May  8 10:08 droplang
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  48K May  8 10:08 dropuser
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 844K May  8 10:08 ecpg
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  98K May  8 10:08 initdb
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  24K May  8 10:08 oid2name
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  15K May  8 10:08 pg_archivecleanup
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  72K May  8 10:08 pg_basebackup
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 121K May  8 10:08 pgbench
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  26K May  8 10:08 pg_config
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  36K May  8 10:08 pg_controldata
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  41K May  8 10:08 pg_ctl
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 379K May  8 10:08 pg_dump
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  85K May  8 10:08 pg_dumpall
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  48K May  8 10:08 pg_isready
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  50K May  8 10:08 pg_receivexlog
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  54K May  8 10:08 pg_recvlogical
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  44K May  8 10:08 pg_resetxlog
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 148K May  8 10:08 pg_restore
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  76K May  8 10:08 pg_rewind
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  20K May  8 10:08 pg_standby
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  18K May  8 10:08 pg_test_fsync
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  13K May  8 10:08 pg_test_timing
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 112K May  8 10:08 pg_upgrade
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  66K May  8 10:08 pg_xlogdump
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 6.2M May  8 10:08 postgres
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    8 Jun  7 20:23 postmaster -> postgres
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 526K May  8 10:08 psql
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  56K May  8 10:08 reindexdb
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  60K May  8 10:08 vacuumdb
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  21K May  8 10:08 vacuumlo
```

Am I missing something here?
How am I supposed to run the initialize database command if the file that is the setup binary (/usr/pgsql-9.6/bin/postgresql96-setup) is missing?

Has the setup binary been deprecated, or do I need to create a link or some other script?
I have even installed PostgreSQL 9.5 to see if the file is present in that release, but it was not.

## Alternative DB Initialization Method

I ran an "alternative" command that was given in an guide for setting up PostgreSQL 9.3 on CentOS 7:

### Initialize the database:

```
sudo service postgresql-9.3 initdb
```

If the previous command failed, call the setup binary directly:

```
sudo /usr/pgsql-9.3/bin/postgresql93-setup initdb
```

### Using the alternative DB Initialization for PostgreSQL 9.6

I ran the command:

```
service postgresql-9.6 initdb
```

which worked, and I was able to setup the database, create a user, create a table, etc., but after reboot the PostgrSQL-9.6 service does not start.

Here is the output of systemctl for postgresql 9.6

```
[root@prdsw1mgtapp39 bin]# systemctl | grep postgres*

UNIT                        LOAD   ACTIVE SUB       DESCRIPTION
● postgresql-9.6.service    loaded failed failed    SYSV: PostgreSQL database server.
```

Here is the systemctl status for postgresql-9.6 service

```
[root@prdsw1mgtapp39 bin]# systemctl status postgresql-9.6.service
● postgresql-9.6.service - SYSV: PostgreSQL database server.
Loaded: loaded (/etc/rc.d/init.d/postgresql-9.6; bad; vendor preset: 
disabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2019-06-09 10:50:27 BST; 
2h 40min ago
Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
Process: 26266 ExecStart=/etc/rc.d/init.d/postgresql-9.6 start 
(code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jun 09 10:50:24 prdsw1mgtapp39 systemd[1]: Starting 
SYSV: PostgreSQL database server....
Jun 09 10:50:27 prdsw1mgtapp39 postgresql-9.6[26266]:                 
Starting postgresql-9.6 service: [FAILED]
Jun 09 10:50:27 prdsw1mgtapp39 systemd[1]: 
postgresql-9.6.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jun 09 10:50:27 prdsw1mgtapp39 systemd[1]: Failed to 
start SYSV: PostgreSQL database server..
Jun 09 10:50:27 prdsw1mgtapp39 systemd[1]: Unit 
postgresql-9.6.service entered failed state.
Jun 09 10:50:27 prdsw1mgtapp39 systemd[1]: 
postgresql-9.6.service failed.
```

I am doing operations as root, and have come across some situations where it complains and tells me to run as a lower privilege user, in which case I open another terminal and logon as a user and use the sudo option if necessary.

Any advice greatly appreciated.